# Scroll Animation on Shape Divider

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am trying to do the curvy background shape divider animation when scrolling on this website (https://crazyabouteggs.com/en/) but I am not sure how.

Does anyone have an idea how this is achieved? Thanks!

**Edited
I have included the image of the divider that I meant here. I'm not sure what it is called in professional term as I did not receive any classes or learn of it before, just learning on my own. I would love to know how the divider curves only when we are scrolling and return to normal when we are not.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ypAS.png

Comment: Please include all relevant information (code, images, details) in the question itself rather than linking to an external site. And what is a "shape divider animation"?

Comment: Have you used your browser's devtools inspect facility to see how they do it?

Comment: https://blog.devgenius.io/wavy-background-with-css-svg-4910821c2b87

Comment: @AHaworth yeah I tried to but I don't really know which one is it, still very new in this.

Comment: @DBS I have updated a screenshot and details of what I meant description, I don't have a code though. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: That (https://crazyabouteggs.com/en/) is a pretty good website. They animate the whole background by giving it momentum. I'm figuring out how using this example: (javascript - Desktop momentum style scrolling and parallax - Stack Overflow). This is our target element in that site: <div class="curved-background"><svg class="curved-background__shape" ... "></path></svg></div>